# Checking second order condition for constrained maximization with slack constraints?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Consider a maximization problem
$$\max_{y_j} f(y_j)$$ subject to two inequality constraints,

- Suppose we know that the inequality constraints are both slack (we have an interior solution)
- then is checking the second order condition the same as in the unconstrained case?

  - (In other words, the second derivative is negative?,
  - If, instead, we had a multivariable maximization problem, then we just need to check that  the hessian is negative semi-definite).

Or would I still need to look at bordered hessians?

Comment: Since you are looking at local conditions, then it reduces to the unconstrained case.